# DigitalWrite Cannot Power HC-06 Bluetooth

Tags: arduino-nano, bluetooth, pins, hc-06, digitalwrite

To save power consumption, I tried to connect the HC-06 bluetooth module to a digital pin of my Arduino Nano. (HC-06 +5V <=> pin 11, HC-06 gnd <=> gnd) In that way, I can toggle the bluetooth when I am not using it. However, when I tried to pinMode(11, OUTPUT) and digitalWrite(11, HIGH), the led on HC-06 does not turn on which means it is not powered. I have tried to connect the HC-06 +5V to the 5V output of arduino and the HC-06 can turn on sucessfully. I have also tried to use a multimeter and the digital pin outputs a voltage of 5V. As the digital pins of Arduino can give 40mA while the HC-06 draws 30mA - 40mA, it should have enough power. I have also tried to use other digital pins as well but still the HC-06 cannot be powered.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is it average or maximum current consumption? And also `40mA` for output pin is listed in section "Absolute Maximum Ratings" and there is also mentioned: "Exposure to absolute maximum rating conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability."

Answer (score 1):

A digital IO pin is only capable of powering an LED or an incredibly low powered device. It is **not** suitable for powering meaty RF modules.

Instead you need to control the power to your module using a P-channel MOSFET as a High-Side switch.

For instance, assuming a 5V module with built in 3.3V LDO:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYSY9f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that `/RFEN` is active low - set the pin OUTPUT and LOW to turn the module on. M1 should have a threshold of no lower than -4V, better -2V or higher.

Also be sure to set RX and TX to be INPUT when you power down the module or back-powering through the TX/RX pins may occur.

R2/R3 is a simple logic level shifter for the 3.3V logic signal the RX pin expects.

Comment: The RX line at least often has a pullup, which should probably be disabled.  And the TX to the module is better driven low than left high.

Answer (score -1):

> it should have enough power.

Probably not. Debugging is about challenging all assumptions, especially implicit ones.

Put a high side switch there and it should be ok.